# Nested for loop between 2 data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, nested

I would like to do the following process :
I have a vector called response_time_to_origin on a side (see the link : [response_time_to_origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReIKj.png)) and on another side a data frame called list_hit_windows (see the link : [list_hit_windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhwV6.png)) containing 3 columns, ie. target_onset, target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000. At each row of this data frame, target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000 should be considered as interval terminals.

Through a bit of code, I would like to know whether, for each row of response_time_to_origin, the value is contained between target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000 at one or more rows of the list_hit_window data frame (if yes, return TRUE, if no return FALSE).

How should I do that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out this useful link on good question practice [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You question needs to show some effort was made by you to solve the problem you are asking as currently it feels like you have been set this as a homework task and are asking the site to do it for you. Lastly ,it is bad practice to post pictures of your data. Instead post a a small amount of your data so we can use it to help solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms I would add list_hit_windows as a new list column in response_time_to_origin. I would then unnest the list column to give you a repeat of list_hit_windows for each value of `response_time_to_origin`. You can then create a dummy variable as to whether each row meets your criteria

```
df %>% mutate(meets_criteria = response_time_to_origin > target_onset_plus200 & response_time_to_origin < target_onset_plus1000)
```

That will give you your TRUE and FALSE column as requested.

You could have a look at the last bit of this answer [R - calculate daily/weekly rate with changing denominator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665698/r-calculate-daily-weekly-rate-with-changing-denominator/71667409#71667409) which is similar and reproducible for you to learn from.

Comment: mkpt_uk I have another question below !

Comment: I think you will need to raise it as a new question not piggy back it on the old one.

Comment: mkpt_uk ok, it will be titled "R - multiple conditions within mutate function" !